# NullReferenceException when reading from a file

Tags: c#, file, arrays, readfile, object-reference

I need to read a file structured like this:

```
01000
00030
00500
03000
00020
```

And put it in an array like this:

```
int[,] iMap = new int[iMapHeight, iMapWidth] {
{0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
{0, 0, 5, 0, 0},
{0, 3, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
};
```

Hopefully you see what I'm trying to do here. I was confused how to do this so I asked here on SO, but the code I got from it gets this error:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

I'm pretty new to this so I have *no* idea how to fix it... I only barely know the code:

```
protected void ReadMap(string mapPath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(mapPath))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iMapHeight; i++)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < iMapWidth; j++)
            {
                iMap[i, j] = (int)(line[j] - '0');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line I get the error on is this:

```
iMap[i, j] = (int)(line[j] - '0');
```

Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Where are you creating the iMap object?  In the constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line, [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) can return null if the end of file is reached:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
```

You should check for this condition and handle it appropriately.

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
if (line == null)
{
    // Handle the error.
}
```

Also make sure that your input has at least `iMapHeight * iMapWidth` lines.

You should also make sure that your array is initialized. For example, add this line to the start of your method:

```
iMap = new int[iMapHeight, iMapWidth];
```